# Impossible to configure JPA connection to my DDB with eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I was using JDBC to test my project and now I generated my entity to use JPA but the connection doesn't work with it:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/test"
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/test"
```

my persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TestPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/test</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I just commented this in my web.xml:

```
<!-- <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/test</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref> -->
```

I searched for 3 hours, any idea?

Comment: i already put in C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar it seems that its the right place

Comment: Done, it dosen't work but thanks anyway

Comment: I deleted the connexion, add a path to the jar in the new connexion, restart the server ect.. but i remember i opened a jpa project it worked without adding.jar, i think its just my configuration but i don't know where

Comment: The driver could possibly be packaged in the project war as a dependency. You could check how it was done in that project. I see now we put the drivers in lib/ext folder

Comment: This should be tagged as glassfish, not JPA/EclipseLink as the issue is with your server and setting up the datasource.  What database are you connecting to - where is the connection details defined?